# How much memory is a table taking up?

Tags: sql-server, memory, cache

Is there a way to find out how much memory a table is taking up in SQL Server (2005 and greater)?

For example, suppose I have a table with 30 million records. I'd like to know how many pages belonging to this table are currently on the buffer cache, [including index, data and text/image pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx).

I found [this query by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/17/sql-server-data-pages-in-buffer-pool-data-stored-in-memory-cache/), but it seems this query only returns pages allocated by indexes (be it clustered or unclustered ones).

Comment: sp_spaceused returns data about the size stored on disk, not what's in memory / in the buffer cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
with bd as (
    select count(*) as pages_in_memory, bd.allocation_unit_id
    from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors bd
    where bd.database_id = db_id()
    group by bd.allocation_unit_id)
select p.object_id,
    p.index_id,
    p.partition_number,
    bd.pages_in_memory,
    au.total_pages as pages_on_disk,
    au.type_desc
from bd 
join sys.allocation_units au 
    on au.allocation_unit_id = bd.allocation_unit_id
join sys.partitions p
    on p.partition_id = au.container_id
```

Comment: If you add some comment to your answer, I'll select it. As it stands, it's not an answer, just some piece of code. (Yes, I know it works, but that is not my point.)